# Terraform Automation Account install SqlServer PS Library

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

while trying to install a module in a automation account I’m getting a error

This is the code

```
resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver" {
  name                    = "xSqlServer"
  resource_group_name     = module.aut_resourcegroup.rg.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.aut.name
  module_link {
    uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/sqlserver.21.1.18256.nupkg"
  }
}
```

This is the error

```
│ Error: waiting for Module "xSqlServer" (Automation Account "aut-eu2-prd-edw-001" / Resource Group "rg-prd-edw-001") to finish provisioning: Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: Cannot import the module of name xSqlServer, as the module structure was invalid.
│    at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext context, Byte[] moduleContent, String moduleName, ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage)
│    at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
│    at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
│    at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
│ 
│   with module.provision_aut[0].module.aut_create["aut-01"].azurerm_automation_module.mod_sqlserver,
│   on _modules/general/aut/aut_create/main.tf line 57, in resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver":
│   57: resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver" {
│ 
╵

##[error]Terraform command 'apply' failed with exit code '1'.
##[error]╷
│ Error: waiting for Module "xSqlServer" (Automation Account "aut-eu2-prd-edw-001" / Resource Group "rg-prd-edw-001") to finish provisioning: Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: Cannot import the module of name xSqlServer, as the module structure was invalid.
│    at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext context, Byte[] moduleContent, String moduleName, ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage)
│    at Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleMetadataAfterValidationActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
│    at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Any ideas on what’s wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

I used the same code as above and got the below error :

[image]

As you are downloading the xSqlServer module not SqlServer module, you can use :

```
uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/xsqlserver.9.1.0.nupkg"
```

Instead of :

```
uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/sqlserver.21.1.18256.nupkg"
```

So the code should be :

```
resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver" {
  name                    = "xSqlServer"
  resource_group_name     = module.aut_resourcegroup.rg.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.aut.name
  module_link {
    uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/xsqlserver.9.1.0.nupkg"
  }
}
```

[image]

If you want to install SqlServer module, you can use the below code :

```
resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver" {
  name                    = "SqlServer"
  resource_group_name     = module.aut_resourcegroup.rg.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.aut.name
  module_link {
    uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/sqlserver.21.1.18256.nupkg"
  }
}
```

[image]